# how to show only limited amount of items from it the app using adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

So I need to show only three objects from my Firebase database on the screen. How can this be implemented?
I retrieve my data using this logic with adapter.

```
retrieveData()
setData(recyclerView)

private fun setData(rec_view:RecyclerView) {

    val query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("News")
    val options = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<News>()
        .setQuery(query, News::class.java)
        .build()
    adapter = object:FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<News, NewsViewHolder>(options){

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NewsViewHolder {
            Log.d("onCreateViewHolder_n", "onCreateViewHolder")

            val newsView = LayoutInflater
                .from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.new_card_new, parent, false)
            return NewsViewHolder(newsView)
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NewsViewHolder, position: Int, model: News) {
            holder.setIsRecyclable(false)
            holder.title.text = model.text
            holder.timestamp.text = model.timestamp
            holder.setNewsClickListener(object: NNewsClickListener {
                override fun onClick(view: View, position: Int) {
                    startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse(model.link)));
                }
            })
        }
    }
    rec_view.adapter = adapter
}

private fun retrieveData() {
    items.clear()
    val db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .reference
        .child("News")
    db.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object :ValueEventListener{

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Log.d("ERROR", "" + error.message)
        }

        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            for(item_newsSnapShot in snapshot.children)
            {
                val item_news = item_newsSnapShot.getValue(News::class.java)
                items.add(item_news!!)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

I found out somewhere that I should use `getItemCount()` or something like this but I'm not sure. If you have any questions regarding my problem, feel free to ask.

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Comment: Alright, good to know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the rest of your code already works, you can limit Firebase to retrieving only 3 items with:

```
val db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    .reference
    .child("News")
    .limitToFirst(3)
```

I recommend checking out the documentation on [sorting and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).

Comment: The code didn't help but the documentation was very helpful. Thanks